# is there reserved words/keywords to continue after you stop the program?

Tags: python-3.x

```
global name_of_file


def create():
    global name_of_file
    enter_name_of_file = str(input("Enter a name of file you want to create: "))
    name_of_file = open(enter_name_of_file+".txt", "w")
    return


create()


def entry_list():
    rep = int(input("How many programming language you want to enter?: "))
    for entry in range(rep):
        file_list = str(input("Enter a programming language: "))
        name_of_file.write(file_list + "\n")
    return

entry_list()


def read():
    global name_of_file
    question = str(input("\nDo you want to read the file? (Y/N): "))
    if question.upper() == "Y" or question.lower() == "y":
        file_name = str(input("Enter the name of the file: "))
        name_of_file = open(file_name, "r")
        print()
        print(name_of_file.read())
        name_of_file.close()
   elif question.upper() == "N" and question.lower() == "n":
        name_of_file.close()
   return


read()
```

I created a program to create a file then put a words in it and read it after. But the file will show after all the functions executed. Is there a code that can stop so that the file will show after the entry list function then continue so I can read the file?

Thank you!

Comment: hey there, I'm not an expert on Python, but there should be a way to open a local file, and wait for user input or putting program to sleep for a few seconds.
Look up Python open local file, Python wait for user input or sleep. What you can do is have the program open local file then have the program wait for an entry/input. This way you can look at the file and when you're done you can enter a key to continue program.

Comment: what part of the above code does not work? Or are you asking for us to write code that will add to this code so it can do what you are asking in the last paragraph? Note that Stack Overflow is not a platform where people can write code for you. It is a platform where others provide you direction and support with your code issues. So please share your code that does not work so we can review and provide guidance.

Comment: One way to do this is to add an input statement where the program waits for the user to prompt an answer. Since the program is waiting for your input, you can use that time to open the file, check what you want, then press the enter key, and the program will continue forward. Thats one way to do it.

Comment: @JoeFerndz, all the codes above is working. In my last paragraph, I just want to know if there is a reserved word/keyword so I can stop/exit and continue the program. But I will try your 2nd comment. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding what you've asked, no, there is not...

In any case, the file is created "after the code ends" because you're only closing the file after you're calling the read function. If you want the file created beforehand, and also  be able to be read it, you must flush or close the file handle

That being said, seems you need a `name_of_file.close()` after the for loop in the entry list function, before you eventually end up opening it again

Also worth pointing out that your create function is going to overwrite any existing files of the entered name